# ngxs: Access different state within Action

Tags: ngxs

Is it possible to access a different state within a action?

Scenario:
I have two states:

- FilterState
- AppState

`FilterState` contains an action `Filter`, when the filter action is triggered, then the `filterService` is called with the payload of the action + with a value from the `AppState`.

```js
@Action(Filter)
filter(ctx, action) {
  // HOW TO GET VALUE FROM AppState

  return this.filterService.filter(action, valueFromOtherStore).pipe(
    tap(data => {
    // Do something with result
    })
  );
}
```

How is it possible to retrieve values from a different state to apply this value to the second param of `this.filterService.filter`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Shared State` documentation answers the question:

- Docs: https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/shared-state

To get access to a different state `selectSnapshot` method on `store` can be used:
`this.store.selectSnapshot(PreferencesState.getSort)`

**Example**

```js
@State<PreferencesStateModel>({
  name: 'preferences',
  defaults: {
    sort: [{ prop: 'name', dir: 'asc' }]
  }
})
export class PreferencesState {
  @Selector()
  static getSort(state: PreferencesStateModel) {
    return state.sort;
  }
}
​
@State<AnimalStateModel>({
  name: 'animals',
  defaults: [
    animals: []
  ]
})
export class AnimalState {
​
  constructor(private store: Store) {}
​
  @Action(GetAnimals)
  getAnimals(ctx: StateContext<AnimalStateModel>) {
    const state = ctx.getState();
​
    // select the snapshot state from preferences
    const sort = this.store.selectSnapshot(PreferencesState.getSort);
​
    // do sort magic here
    return state.sort(sort);
  }
​
}
```

Comment: I still get undefined  when using selectSnapshot

Comment: Using snapshot will return undefined if the other state is being initiated asynchronously. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53437903/4663041) is how I've solve that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Selecting the snapshot will return undefined as the other state hasn't been initiated yet, I've solved the problem by using a normal select and filtering the result.

```js
@State<PreferencesStateModel>({
  name: 'preferences',
  defaults: {
    sort: [{ prop: 'name', dir: 'asc' }]
  }
})
export class PreferencesState {
  @Selector()
  static getSort(state: PreferencesStateModel) {
    return state.sort;
  }
}
​
@State<AnimalStateModel>({
  name: 'animals',
  defaults: [
    animals: []
  ]
})
export class AnimalState {
​
  constructor(private store: Store) {}
​
  @Action(GetAnimals)
  getAnimals(ctx: StateContext<AnimalStateModel>) {
    const state = ctx.getState();
​
    // select the snapshot state from preferences
    return this.store.select(PreferencesState.getSort)
    .pipe(
       filter(sort => sort !== undefined),
       take(1),
       map(sort => {
           // do sort magic here
           return state.sort(sort);
       })
    );
​
}
```